# PHP7.1/Xdebug crashed on MacOs

Tags: php, macos, xdebug

I recently reinstalled MacBook. Before installing MacOs everything worked fine. After installing MacOs, I installed php7.1 and xdebug on macos (sierra 10.12 (16A323)) with brew.

```
brew install homebrew/php/php71
brew install homebrew/php/php71-xdebug
```

After installation, I configured nginx, php.ini (php-fpm) and PhpStorm. See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/configuring-xdebug.html

```
#ext-xdebug.ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable = 0 
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0 
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1"
xdebug.idekey="PHPStorm"
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
```

Info:

```
macbook:Install shranet$ php -m | grep -i xdebug
xdebug
Xdebug
macbook:Install shranet$ php --version
PHP 7.1.0RC3 (cli) (built: Oct  5 2016 14:17:16) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
macbook:Install shranet$
```

Everything works fine without debugging. When I want to debug php-fpm crashed.

In syslog:

```
...
Oct 13 13:51:09 macbook ReportCrash[32952]: Saved crash report for php-fpm[23776] version 0 to /Users/shranet/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/php-fpm_2016-10-13-135109_macbook.crash
...
```

Crash file:

```
Process:               php-fpm [23776]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.0-rc.3_8/sbin/php-fpm
Identifier:            php-fpm
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        php-fpm [23693]
Responsible:           php-fpm [23776]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-10-13 13:51:09.251 +0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12 (16A323)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        03175328-17C1-1699-D293-CBE89EE06B26

Sleep/Wake UUID:       CE27B595-2027-4FE0-BEAB-5EC3D82E03C5

Time Awake Since Boot: 210000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       8400 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000200000010
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x200000010:
    __LINKEDIT             000000010fadd000-000000010faf3000 [   88K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld
--> 
    MALLOC_TINY            00007fdd91c00000-00007fdd92000000 [ 4096K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  

Application Specific Information:
crashed on child side of fork pre-exec

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fffa8c13b92 strlen + 18
1   xdebug.so                       0x0000000102c593b9 check_evaled_code + 39
2   xdebug.so                       0x0000000102c591fd xdebug_dbgp_breakpoint + 430
3   xdebug.so                       0x0000000102c54078 xdebug_statement_call + 324
4   php-fpm                         0x0000000101d2742a zend_llist_apply_with_argument + 31
5   php-fpm                         0x0000000101d973aa ZEND_EXT_STMT_SPEC_HANDLER + 47
6   php-fpm                         0x0000000101d704cb execute_ex + 44
7   php-fpm                         0x0000000101d23bd1 dtrace_execute_ex + 238
8   xdebug.so                       0x0000000102c531ff xdebug_execute_ex + 1996
9   php-fpm                         0x0000000101d70743 zend_execute + 551
10  php-fpm                         0x0000000101d32fb6 zend_execute_scripts + 307
11  php-fpm                         0x0000000101cdb102 php_execute_script + 770
12  php-fpm                         0x0000000101dd7e2b main + 6295
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffa8bdd255 start + 1

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
rax: 0x00007fdd91da5d00  rbx: 0x000000020000001e  rcx: 0x000000020000001e  rdx: 0x000000020000001e
rdi: 0x0000000200000010  rsi: 0x00007fff5e249fc0  rbp: 0x00007fff5e249f50  rsp: 0x00007fff5e249f50
r8: 0x0000000000000030   r9: 0x00007fdd91da5d00  r10: 0x00000000fff80000  r11: 0x0000000000000007
r12: 0x00007fdd91d9a6d0  r13: 0x00007fdd91da5d00  r14: 0x00007fff5e249fc0  r15: 0x0000000102c75618
rip: 0x00007fffa8c13b92  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000200000010

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
    0x1019b5000 -        0x102323ff3 +php-fpm (0) <5E39E45F-C0F5-3B7B-8D4C-EDA207F6038F> /usr/local/opt/php71/sbin/php-fpm
    0x1024d0000 -        0x1024d8ff3 +libintl.8.dylib (0) <9A1967E0-AC59-3EF6-B14F-643AF08A6B4F> /usr/local/opt/gettext/lib/libintl.8.dylib
    0x1024e3000 -        0x102506ffb +libpng16.16.dylib (0) <01088AC2-5BF8-3B05-AD2D-29A5DA7DD88C> /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
    0x10250f000 -        0x10253aff7 +libjpeg.8.dylib (0) <F058D36A-6433-3380-A15D-BF1B2C7CCC5B> /usr/local/opt/jpeg/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
    0x102542000 -        0x1026b4af7 +libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (0) <BA2A57BB-4346-303E-A1E8-7862E6752057> /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
    0x102732000 -        0x102771ff7 +libssl.1.0.0.dylib (0) <E105E614-7546-3784-975F-C5278723D08C> /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
    0x102790000 -        0x102880fff +libxml2.2.dylib (0) <2452DC63-673D-361E-BEB7-90091006445A> /usr/local/opt/libxml2/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    ... 

External Modification Summary:
Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 488
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 241766
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 4430

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=205.1M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=205.1M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=51.6M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=51.6M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
MALLOC                            37.3M       11 
MALLOC guard page                   16K        4 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        2 
Stack                             8192K        2 
VM_ALLOCATE                       6348K        9 
__DATA                            10.2M      158 
__LINKEDIT                       112.9M       15 
__TEXT                            92.2M      158 
__UNICODE                          556K        2 
shared memory                       12K        4 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            323.4M      356
```

I searched the internet but found nothing. Sorry, my english is bad so i'm using google translate.

**Update:**

I downgraded to php5.6 and debugger works correctly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and congratulations for an excellent first question. I hope someone will be able to help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Now I installed php70 and php70-xdebug

```
brew install php70 --with-apache
brew install homebrew/php/php70-xdebug
```

Now debugging with phpstorm is working fine again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience after installing xdebug via "brew install php71-xdebug". In trying to resolve the issue, I cross checked the version of xdebug previously installed via "brew install php70-xdebug" which worked correctly at the time. I discovered the latter had a newer version of xdebug installed (2.4.1) while the former reported xdebug version 2.4.0 as the latest update. This gave me a hint on what was needed, I'd have to compile from source a newer version of xdebug.

Here are the steps I took.

First, you would need to know the path to phpize and php-config on your system and have git installed `brew install git`. A default brew install of php will place both phpize and php-config in a "bin" folder within a "php version only" named folder and php** folder located in "/usr/local/Cellar". e.g /usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.0-rc.5_9/bin/phpize and /usr/local/Cellar/php71/7.1.0-rc.5_9/bin/php-config

```
cd /tmp
git clone git://github.com/xdebug/xdebug.git
cd xdebug
```

then run phpsize and configure with php-config

```
/{your path to phpize}/phpize
./configure --enable-xdebug --with-php-config=/{your path to php-config}/php-config
make
cp modules/xdebug.so {path to preferred location. e.g /usr/local/opt/php71-xdebug}
```

restart php and your webserver